# Is there a Pac-Man-like character in ASCII or Unicode?

Tags: unicode, special-characters

Simple question: **is there a character that looks either like Pac-Man, or like the ghost in Pac-Man?**

With Google's recent Pac-Man logo, everyone should know what these look like, but in case you don't here are some sample images:

[image] [image]

If you answer "no" please provide a little more proof that you actually searched all unicode characters...

---

**Example of what I'm looking for:** If I were to ask, "is there a character that looks like a sun", I would expect an answer along the lines of "Yes, ☼ and according to charmap it is U+263C". That's what I'm looking for, but with Pac-Man or the ghost...

---

**Usage:** I would like to paste this symbol into a web form textbox in order for it to show on a webpage. This is a one-line textbox, so a complex ASCII art "image" isn't acceptable in this case.

Comment: How about the letters "C" and "A"?

Comment: So you, if we answer "no", you expect us to prove it by checking every unicode character?  In other words, you want us to do the work for you?

Comment: Unicode U+25D4 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25d4/index.htm. There's also plenty of hollow triangles in the same block should you be thinking of building an asteroids clone! :)

Comment: @Neil If you use A they'll get confused and say WTF is the Asteroids ship doing in PACMAN???

Comment: @Chris: No, he's saying that if you're not sure, don't say "no". That's pretty reasonable.

Comment: Back in the 8-bit era I saw a five-line game inspired by Pacman. I don't recall what it used for the main character, but the ghost was a reverse-video `"`.

Comment: We've come a long way since this was originally posted -- now Pacman is just about* the only thing we *don't* have!
 Ghost
 Cherry
 Strawberry
 Orange
 Apple
 Melon
 Bell
 Key
(* ok, and the Galaxian Boss...)

Comment: The copyright symbol ;-)

Comment: @deltab 8 years later I search for "8 bit five line pacman" and find this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o9J8d5D99A :-)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

ᗤ <- pacman, also a ghost ᗣ got here by google, someone else will be looking for it, don't remember the unicode for it but i copied the characters from a old file.

Comment: Good find.  ᗣ is U+15E3, ᗤ U+15E4, and ᗧ U+15E7.  They're labeled as CANADIAN SYLLABICS CARRIER TTO, TTE, and TTA, respectively.

Comment: Hence, Pᗣᗧ•••MᗣN ?

Comment: Hence 2, ᗧ•••ᗣ••

Comment: ·····•····· ᗤ ᗣᗣᗣᗣ

Comment: And Up is ᗢ U+15E7 ("TTU")

Comment: ᗧ···········ᗣ

Answer (score 11):

I know it's not quite what you asked, but Pacman makes an appearance in the discotastic [DF Strand Midnight](http://marketplace.veer.com/type/DET0000298) typeface.

[image: DF Strand]

Answer (score 10):

It's not looking good -- presumably, anything resembling Pac-Man would be in [the "Geometric Shapes" block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes_Unicode_block), but the closest you'll get is a circle that's 1/4 filled:

> ◔
>   ◕
>   ◴ 
>   ◵ 
>   ◶ 
>   ◷

Comment: I like the first one you posed; I used it and it is close enough to Pac-Man; you can definitely see the resemblance! Thanks :)

Comment: The copyright symbol looks more like it than those ;-)  Or the letter C

Answer (score 10):

For finding unicode symbols that look like things, I use the [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/) website. It allows you to draw an example and then does an image search. Though you may need to use a few tries to find what you're looking for. This is surprisingly handy to use, for example I've used it to look for unicode characters that look like application icons.

If I draw a crude left-facing Pacman outline, about half-way through the results I get the

> Canadian syllabics carrier tte: ᗤ

as found in the [top answer](https://superuser.com/a/357916/367183).

Answer (score 7):

This is the most similar I could find:

> ᗧ

Answer (score 7):

On 1/25/2022 Pacman glyph in all (four) directions got accepted to Unicode as part of the 731 legacy computing symbols proposed in [L2/21-235](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2021/21235-terminals-supplement.pdf) in a new block named "Symbols for Legacy Computing Supplement" for a future version of the Unicode standard.

See pages 22 and 26 in above linked proposal; under "Game Sprites" symbols `1CC6B` to `1CC6E`.

[image: Game Sprites]

This was announced by The Unicode Consortium on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/unicode/status/1486163677803806722?s=20)

Answer (score 6):

No. Unicode does not provide amusing characters just for the fun of it--all of the wacky characters in Unicode (like the snowman and the sun) are there because some legacy encoding included them.

No legacy character set ever had a Pac-Man character. Hence, Pac-Man is not in Unicode.

If you're trying to find out if there's some oddball character that kinda-sorta *resembles* Pac-Man, you'll have to look through all of the codepages yourself.

Comment: What about the snowman? ☃ He's kind of an amusing character.

Comment: I mentioned the snowman as an example of an oddball character that's in a legacy character set.

Comment: @mipadi: The snowman is a weather symbol.

Comment: What about emojis? Do they all map to some **legacy** Unicode code point?

Comment: This is now outdated, what with  and emojis.

Comment: This was never quite accurate, a few non-arcade systems did include Pac-Man and/or similar sprite characters in their ROMs. As alluded to in blami's answer, when Unicode 16 is released then Unicode will include those characters as well.

Answer (score 5):

No.

> If you answer "no" please provide a little more proof that you actually searched all unicode characters...

Did *you* search all the unicode characters?

Comment: I guess they didn't want to put that much effort in it :)

Comment: Thanks for contributing nothing with a low-effort "answer".

Answer (score 5):

( *< • • •

^ closest I can get to making Pacman with text

Answer (score 4):

### ଓ

I think this looks like Pac-Man!

Answer (score 2):

The list of characters slated for Unicode 6.0 includes U+1F47B GHOST.

Comment: Hmm, [it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f47b/browsertest.htm) [doesn’t look](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f47b/ghost.png) like a ghost. `o.O`

Comment: @Synetech Eh, kinda. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEc3o.png) is what it looks like in my browser.

Comment: It depends on the font. Different browsers use different default styles and thus font families.

Answer (score 2):

I know CSS3 is kind'a cheating but could not resist rotating 45deg.. and adding animation to make pack-man "chew"..

https://jsbin.com/nasexevolo/edit?html,css,output

[image]
[image]

it's also content-dynamic, since you can place any two symbos in `state-a` and `state-b`

:) ☕